# How can I save my GAN generated images after every epoch?

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision, generative-adversarial-network, torchvision

I tried to build my very own GAN in PyTorch. I wanted to see how my model learns to generate images over time, I tried to save images it created after each epoch but it saved the same image after every epoch. I guess I do save the same image everytime. You can see first 3 epochs' [images](https://imgur.com/a/rDEDthD)
In addition, as you can see, it combines all images to save, can I choose only 1?

```py
class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, img_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.disc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(img_dim, 128),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.1),
            nn.Linear(128, 1),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.disc(x)
        
class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, z_dim, img_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.gen = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(z_dim, 512),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.1),
            nn.Linear(512, 1024),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.1),
            nn.Linear(1024, img_dim),
            nn.Tanh() 
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.gen(x)
lr = 3e-4
z_dim = 64
image_dim = 256 * 256 * 3
batch_size = 32
num_epochs = 16

disc = Discriminator(image_dim).to(device)
gen = Generator(z_dim, image_dim).to(device)
fixed_noise = torch.randn((batch_size, z_dim)).to(device)

# dataset = load_dataset(data_path="mountain_dataset", transform=transform)
loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=32, num_workers=0, shuffle=True)
opt_disc = optim.Adam(disc.parameters(), lr=lr)
opt_gen = optim.Adam(gen.parameters(), lr=lr)
criterion = nn.BCELoss()
```

second part:

```py
from torchvision.utils import save_image

step = 0

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for batch_idx, real in enumerate(dataset):
        real = real.view(-1, image_dim).to(device)
        batch_size = real.shape[0]

        ### Train Discriminator: max log(D(real)) + log(1 - D(G(z)))
        noise = torch.randn(batch_size, z_dim).to(device)
        fake = gen(noise)
        disc_real = disc(real).view(-1)
        lossD_real = criterion(disc_real, torch.ones_like(disc_real))

        disc_fake = disc(fake).view(-1)
        lossD_fake = criterion(disc_fake, torch.zeros_like(disc_fake))
        lossD = (lossD_real + lossD_fake) / 2

        disc.zero_grad()
        lossD.backward(retain_graph=True)
        opt_disc.step()

        ### Train Generator maximize log(D(G(z)))
        output = disc(fake).view(-1)
        lossG = criterion(output, torch.ones_like(output))
        gen.zero_grad()
        lossG.backward()
        opt_gen.step()

        
        if batch_idx == 0:
            print(
                f"Epoch: [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}]"
            )

            with torch.no_grad():
                fake = gen(fixed_noise).reshape(-1, 3, 256, 256)
                data = real.reshape(-1, 3, 256, 256)
                img_grid_fake = torchvision.utils.make_grid(fake, normalize=True)
                img_grid_real = torchvision.utils.make_grid(data, normalize=True)

                # Convert the NumPy array to a PyTorch tensor
                img_grid_fake_tensor = img_grid_fake
                
                # Save the PyTorch tensor as an image
                save_image(img_grid_fake_tensor, f"generated_images/epoch{epoch}.png", normalize=True)
                
                step += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Question 1: Images are the same

First, in the line `for batch_idx, real in enumerate(dataset):` you iterate over the dataset.
I.e., `real` represents one image, not one batch. If you add the line `print(real.shape)` as the first line after the loop, this will print `torch.Size([3, 256, 256])` which is one image rather than one batch. Accordingly, your batch_size will always be three and actually be the number of channels.

So you have to change this line to `for batch_idx, real in enumerate(loader):`. Then, the print will give you `torch.Size([32, 3, 256, 256])`, which is what you actually want.

After that modification, the saved images are different after each epoch for the first few epochs. I tested this with Cifar10 upscaled:

```
dataset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root="dataset/", transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose([
    torchvision.transforms.Resize(image_shape),
    torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
    torchvision.transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))
    ]), download=True)
dataset = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset, range(0, 1000))
loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, pin_memory=True)
```

However, after 3 epochs, the generated images stay indeed the same. This is because your model stops learning.

```
Epoch: [1/16] Loss D: 0.6715, Loss G: 3.8073
Epoch: [2/16] Loss D: 50.3202, Loss G: 0.0000
Epoch: [3/16] Loss D: 50.0000, Loss G: 0.0000
Epoch: [4/16] Loss D: 50.0030, Loss G: 0.0000
Epoch: [5/16] Loss D: 50.0000, Loss G: 0.0000
```

You will have to modify your architecture in order to keep training for more epochs. For instance, your discriminator is much smaller than the generator. As a starting point, you might want to have both models to have a similar number of parameters. Your can see the parameter count like this:

```
print(
    f"Discriminator Parameters:\t{sum(p.numel() for p in disc.parameters())}\n"
    f"Generator Parameters:\t\t{sum(p.numel() for p in gen.parameters())}"
)
```

For instance, increasing the discriminator like this gives me an additional three epochs of learning:

```
class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, img_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.disc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(img_dim, 512),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.1),
            nn.Linear(512, 1024),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.1),
            nn.Linear(1024, 1),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )
```

### Question 2: How to save only one image

With the line `img_grid_fake = torchvision.utils.make_grid(fake, normalize=True)`, you create a grid of all 32 (batch_size) images which is then saved to a file.

If you only want to randomly choose four of these for saving, you could do this like that:

```
fake = gen(fixed_noise).reshape(-1, 3, 256, 256)
# Select 4 random images to print
fake = random.choices(fake, k=4)
img_grid_fake = torchvision.utils.make_grid(fake, normalize=True, nrow=2)
```

If you only want to save a single image instead of a grid:

```
# Print only image number 6
index = 5 # For random: random.randint(0, batch_size-1)
fake = gen(fixed_noise[index]).reshape(3, 256, 256)
save_image(fake, f"generated_images/epoch{epoch}.png", normalize=True)
```

#### Note

I deleted the lines

```
data = real.reshape(-1, 3, 256, 256)
img_grid_real = torchvision.utils.make_grid(data, normalize=True)
```

are unnecessary because unless you actually want to print some real samples, too.